# Page navigation - keeping data on previous page

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

In a windows phone app,a page is navigated to another page and on pressing back button, goes back to previous page.Now in previous page the previous data has to be displayed. But its not displaying immediately and takes some time to load. How to solve this issue?
Overall the question is how to maintain the content of page(containing dynamic data) displayed in back navigation?

Comment: for example,in UC browse, when we come back to previous page the previous data is not cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PhoneApplicationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class to keep the data while you navigate between the pages. Here is [some samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Actually, it's very easy:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs args)
{ 
    if (ContentPanel.Background is SolidColorBrush) 
    { 
        Color clr = (ContentPanel.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color; 
        if (args.Content is MainPage) (args.Content as MainPage).ReturnedColor = clr; 
        // save color
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Color"] = clr; 
    } 
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(args); 
} 

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs args) 
{ 
    // restore color
    if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.ContainsKey("Color")) 
    { 
        Color clr = (Color)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Color"];
        ContentPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(clr);
    } 
    base.OnNavigatedTo(args); 
}
```

Comment: There is a sample code inside the answer. Do you have some difficulties with this code?

Comment: Actually in my application, pages contain lists which loads data from servers and what should I pass in OnNavigatedFrom and To methods?

Comment: What do you want to store? Entire lists?

Comment: there are few choices. if list is simple, like names, concatenate them into one string and then save. On load, split the save big string into  pieces and populate the list.

Answer (score 0):

[How to preserve and restore page state for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967548%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: crea7or provided some sample code . The idea is that you store your page's state in the `PhoneApplicationService` dictionary or in your PhoneApplicagePage.State dictionary on `OnNavigatedFrom()` when you navigate away from a page and restore it on `NavigatedTo()` when you navigate back to that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single ton object of View Model to store data in a page provided all the controls are bind to a property in View Model.
Then if you do not clear the values of the controls when navigating away from the page, the data will be displayed in the page when you navigate back to that screen provided all the controls